# .read() method doesn't read my file

Tags: python, file, text, methods

I'm learning python following this documentation:

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

I'm trying to read my file named "plik.txt". It consists two short lines of text like:

```
long time ago 
blah blah...
```

So I use this code:

```
 f = open('C:\Users\PC\Desktop\plik.txt', 'r+b')
 print f
 f.read()
```

However all I got is message

```
<open file 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\plik.txt', mode 'r+b' at 0x053EC7B0>
```

I'm using canopy.

What doesn't my program show (just like in instruction) text in my file?

Comment: You should print `f.read()` not `f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading the file just fine, but are printing the *file object*, not the file contents.

Use `print f.read()` instead:

```
f = open('C:\Users\PC\Desktop\plik.txt', 'r+b')
print f.read()
```

The `.read()` method *returns* the file contents but you were ignoring them entirely.

The Python tutorial also assumes you are running the code in the interactive Python interpreter, which automatically echos the return value of any expression that doesn't result in `None`. Thus, calling `f.read()` includes an automatic `print repr(returnvalue)` for everything you do.

You must be running your code directly, not in the interactive interpreter, where the automatic echo is not present and you don't get to see what `f.read()` returned unless you explicitly print it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
f = open('C:\Users\PC\Desktop\plik.txt', 'r+b')
print f.read()
```

that will print what you have read from f, while `print f` would print information about the object `f`, the file object.

Answer (score 0):

`open` returns a handle to a file. you assign this handle to `f`.
`print f` prints the handle (with file name, mode etc.)
you should print the result of `f.read()` instead.

It makes a difference if you put the following code in a file and run it with `python filename.py` or you enter the code in a python interpreter:

Running `python filename.py` with following code

```
f = open('C:\Users\PC\Desktop\plik.txt', 'r+b')
print f
f.read()
```

will only print the result of `print f`

If you type the same code in a python interpreter

```
>>> f = open('C:\Users\PC\Desktop\plik.txt', 'r+b')
>>> print f
<open file 'C:\Users\PC\Desktop\plik.txt', mode 'r+b' at 0xb7382020>
>>> f.read()
'the content of file C:\Users\PC\Desktop\plik.txt ...'
```

if will print the result f.read() after you enter it.